# How to create a stored procedure using declare variables in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want to create a stored procedure in PL/SQL using declare variable. But it did not work. How can I create this?

My code looks like:

```sql
create or replace procedure only_for_test as
begin
declare
maxdate date;
BEGIN
SELECT to_date(max(create_date)) 
INTO maxdate
FROM table_a where product = 'A' and create_date >= date'2023-09-01';
END;
if
maxdate = to_date(sysdate)
then
begin
proc_test;
end;
end if;
commit;
end only_for_test;
```

The above code showing error:

> PLS-00201: identifier 'MAXDATE' must be declared
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Please help me. Thank you a lot.

Comment: I don't know where you learned PL/SQL but I'm guessing that you did **not** read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/index.html).

Comment: Declarations should be placed between `AS` and `BEGIN`.

Comment: @Abra yah, I just use BigQuery before. For PL/SQL I'm very new. Maybe I need to read more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have nested PL/SQL blocks and you have tried to use `MAXDATE` in the outer block when it is only `DECLARE`d in the inner block.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE only_for_test
AS                  -- Variable definitions for outer block
BEGIN               -- Begin outer block
  DECLARE           -- Variable definitions for inner block
    maxdate DATE;
  BEGIN             -- Begin inner block
    -- ...          -- Do stuff in the inner block
  END;              -- End the inner block
                    -- maxdate was declared in the inner block and stops being
                    -- usable when you end the block
  -- ...            -- Do stuff in the outer block
END only_for_test;  -- End the outer block
/
```

Start by creating an anonymous PL/SQL block (rather than a procedure) and test that what you want to do works:

```sql
DECLARE
  maxdate DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT TRUNC(MAX(create_date))
  INTO   maxdate
  FROM   table_a
  WHERE  product = 'A'
  AND    create_date >= DATE '2023-09-01';

  IF maxdate = TRUNC(sysdate) THEN
    proc_test;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Note:

- Unless you are catching exceptions, you (almost always) want a single `DECLARE` where you declare the variables and then a single `BEGIN` and an `END` at the end.
- **NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE`. If you want to compare values ignoring the time component of a `DATE` then use the `TRUNC` to truncate the dates back to midnight.
- You should not `COMMIT` in procedures as this prevents you from running multiple procedures and then using `ROLLBACK` to rollback the changes from the 1st procedure if a later procedure fails. Instead, `COMMIT` from the code that calls the procedure.

Once a simple PL/SQL block is working then swap the `DECLARE` statement at the start of the block for the procedure signature:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE only_for_test
AS
  maxdate DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT TRUNC(MAX(create_date))
  INTO   maxdate
  FROM   table_a
  WHERE  product = 'A'
  AND    create_date >= DATE '2023-09-01';

  IF maxdate = TRUNC(sysdate) THEN
    proc_test;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful guide. My issue was resolved with this.

Answer (score 0):

It is about a scope. Read comments within the following code.

First, test procedure (to avoid error that it doesn't exist):

```
SQL> CREATE PROCEDURE proc_test
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4     NULL;
  5  END;
  6  /
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_test
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

This is your procedure (modified a little bit so that it runs in my schema):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE only_for_test
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4     DECLARE
  5        maxdate  DATE;          --> this MAXDATE is local to its own DECLARE-BEGIN-END block
  6     BEGIN                      --> and you can use it whererver you want, but only within its block
  7        SELECT TO_DATE (MAX (hiredate))
  8          INTO maxdate
  9          FROM emp
 10         WHERE     job = 'CLERK'
 11               AND hiredate >= DATE '1980-09-01';
 12     END;
 13
 14     IF maxdate = TO_DATE (SYSDATE) --> referencing it here is out-of-scope, it doesn't exist
 15     THEN                           --> in this context
 16        BEGIN
 17           proc_test;
 18        END;
 19     END IF;
 20
 21     COMMIT;
 22  END only_for_test;
 23  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE ONLY_FOR_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
14/4     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
14/7     PLS-00201: identifier 'MAXDATE' must be declared
SQL>
```

This is what works - variable is declared at procedure's level:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE only_for_test
  2  AS
  3     maxdate  DATE; --> if you declare it here, on procedure level, then ...
  4  BEGIN
  5     BEGIN
  6        SELECT TO_DATE (MAX (hiredate))
  7          INTO maxdate
  8          FROM emp
  9         WHERE     job = 'CLERK'
 10               AND hiredate >= DATE '1980-09-01';
 11     END;
 12
 13     IF maxdate = TO_DATE (SYSDATE) --> ... you CAN reference it through the whole procedure
 14     THEN
 15        BEGIN
 16           proc_test;
 17        END;
 18     END IF;
 19
 20     COMMIT;
 21  END only_for_test;
 22  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```